# How data is sent to a raw TFT?

Tags: fpga, lcd, rgb, tft

I have used TFT drivers before but now I want to challenge myself by connecting an FPGA to a raw TFT without a driver.
I am having hard time understanding the basics of the signals : how RGB pins are clocked according to HSYNC and VSYNC pins ?
After so much searching I think I am supposed to signal both HSYNC and VSYNC as start in (0,0) data and then to place each row’s dot RGB data with each clock pulse but can’t figure what I should do to H and VSYNC at each row / column change ? [image]

Comment: The detailed diagrams are on pages 8 and 9 - is there a specific question about them?

Comment: `I am supposed to signal both HSYNC and VSYNC` ... that still involves the driver .... raw interface would involve driving rows and columns

Comment: @Justme in page 7 seems VSYNC and HSYNC are active low while in page 8 they are active high.  on the other hand I cant figure what I am supposed to do with DE . is it a separate mode or just need to be set high during the data transfer.  same is ambiguous with ON_OFF , is screen on on 1 or 0 ?  combination of me being a newbie and vague datasheet !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical Sync or Frame Sync `VSYNC` defines the start and duration of a frame so one full picture, within this frame every column is initiated with the Horizontal Sync or Column Sync `HSYNC`.

So `VSYNC` is active for a whole frame and `HSYNC` is active for a whole column. Before both there's a backporch time, you should find these in the display's datasheet, during which the signal has to be low.

For example in [this](https://www.densitron.com/sites/default/files/2019-10/DMT040QBHTNT0-1A.pdf) datasheet on page 17 you find the interface timings.

Comment: Actually I am working on this one but the data sheet is so vague about all that timing.  Do you think I should buy another type?  https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2354/adafruit_SPEC-YX700WV03_REV.A-787880.pdf

Comment: It's indeed not a good datasheet, but I think you can figure out the timings with try and error. I'd start with alternating colored columns to see if your sync is correct. https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/KD50G21-40NT-A1.pdf seems to be better